# crtmqm: command not found

Tags: ibm-mq

I have installed a trial version of MQ and now im trying to create a queue manager.
Running the command crtmqm gives

```
crtmqm -q QManager
bash: crtmqm: command not found
```

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely the case that your path isn't set up correctly.

Find out where the `crtmqm` is located (such as with `find / -name crtmqm`) and add that directory to your path (in your favorite startup file, like `.profile` or `.bash_profile`).

You *may* also then need to open up a new session (or even log in again), depending on which startup file was changed.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem in using IBM MQ V7.5. In that i could get rid of this by setting the path to the directory which i have these executable files which i created in the 6th step of following the [blog - Enterprise Messaging with Synapse, WSO2 ESB and WebSphere MQ](http://techfeast-hiranya.blogspot.com/2009/09/enterprise-messaging-with-synapse-wso2.html)

To set the patch , i added the line `export PATH=$PATH:/home/wso2/mqm/bin` to the `.bashrc` file of the user and executed the `source .bashrc` command.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely cause is that you did not run [`setmqinst`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/fa15635_.htm).

When WebSphere MQ gained multiple install capability, it became necessary to explicitly tell WMQ which install you want to use as the default.  This is especially important when the multiple installs are of different versions and the API may have changed or the classes repackaged a bit.  Running `setmqinst` sources the correct set of libraries, classes, etc.  Full details are at the Infocenter page linked above.

Unfortunately, setting the `PATH` as recommended by other respondents only works in the narrow case that there is only one install of WMQ and it is in the default location.